# Should I flag off-topic answers or comments but with good sense of humour?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, flags, off-topic

It is quite obvious for me that flagging off-topic answers are pretty much always welcomed.
I have however problem with comments:

Recently I flagged **off-topic comment** but then I felt sorry for a guy because his comment was very **funny**,short and introduced so much freshness to the topic and revived it a bit.
One could say: it invited 'out of the box' type of thinking.

Another reason of feeling bad was the fact, that it made me think of how serious we should be in our community? Can we allow some off-topic fun from time to time? Especially when they are very short and do not produce much noise?

**Example**:

question: `How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?`
comment: `don't bother migrate to droid :)`

From: [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

If this is acceptable - can you provide other examples of acceptable off-topic posts?

Comment: That's a very poor example you give there. That's neither an on-topic, nor constructive nor funny comment. It's not exactly that bad either, though. Some of [the highest upvoted comments on SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80578) are jokes or flat out comedy.

Comment: It was very funny for all of the developers in my team. Seems to be matter of taste.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is yes.

There is a [StackExchange blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) on the issue, although that is more about "fun questions".
Quoting from that blog post:

> only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated, and always with steely, businesslike frowns. :)

Personally, I don't mind the occassional funny comment, especially on Meta. (Pleading guilty - I sometimes crack a little joke in the comments myself).
But if it is an *answer* is humorous, yet fails to answer the question - I flag it, it should then be either a comment or deleted altogether.

Comment: I hope on April Fools, you postpone the flag until midnight ;)

Comment: Please modify your "short answer" to reflect the fact that you're talking about questions and answers, but NOT comments...

Comment: @Benjol The same holds for questions, answers and comments: humour is not so much allowed as it is tolerated. I would probably have flagged the "migrate to droid" comment in the example, to prevent it from starting a holy war.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That was exactly what I did eventually: flagged it. It turned out, the author of the comment lost his sense of humor because I got first down-vote few minutes after moderator removed it. It might have been coincidence, but quite big one then.

Comment: @Lukasz If it was really a "vengeance downvote", and not a coincidence... then pity on him/her. IMO you did the right thing.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, sorry, I just can't agree that you should flag humourous comments. As Uniconified Bobby said, the example comment in the question is a bad one, because it could have been construed as flame bait.